# Apache Aliases not working ... but only on some virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, alias

Running Mac OS X Server with Apache 2.2, and I have a number of virtual hosts configured.  We have a content management system that we offer our clients, and have an alias setup to map each individual client to the shared codebase as follows:

Alias "/admin" "/path/to/admin"

This alias is working on most of our virtual hosts, but failing on one or two ... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

File or directory permission problems?

Search into apache log files any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was caused by a misconfiguration - I had effectively duplicated one of my virtual host records (2 different host records, but had a server alias pointing at each one).  Once the duplicate record was removed, all was fine.